# Transitions in navigation bar same as IOS Music App

Tags: ios, swift2, uinavigationbar

how can we get this navigation bar transition effects ?? (same as apple's Music App)

**IMAGE1**

in this image we have a navigation bar which is totally transparent only the navigation bar buttons are visible
[image: image 1]

**IMAGE2**

as you scroll up bar gets blurred
 same when you scroll down bar gets less blurred 
[image: IMAGE2]

**IMAGE3**

and after a certain point  navigation bar becomes The default navigation bar with Title in it
[image: IMAGE3]

anybody can guide me how to achieve this above mentioned Transitions Effect

what i have right now is

```
    func addBlurEffect() {
    // Add blur view
    var bounds = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds as CGRect!
    visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark))
    bounds.offsetInPlace(dx: 0.0, dy: -20.0)
    bounds.size.height = bounds.height + 20.0
    visualEffectView.frame = bounds
    visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(visualEffectView)


    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.sendSubviewToBack(visualEffectView)

 }
```

am able to make blur my bar but i want it to blur it as Music app in iOS

Comment: It **had** to be Justin Beaver :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to use the scroll offset to set the alpha for the `visualEffectView.` Then when the image is the height of navigationBar from being completely off the screen you switch from the transparent nav bar to the normal translucent one. I created a view controller class that can do this using a `UIScrollView`, but the same principle applies to `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`.

```
import UIKit

class NavigationBlurViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    // Might not want to hard code the height of the navBar but YOLO
    let navBarHeight: CGFloat = 66.0

    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return scrollView
    }()

    let contentView = UIView()

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Swift")
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        return imageView
    }()

    lazy var visualEffectView: UIVisualEffectView = {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
        let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        visualEffectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        visualEffectView.alpha = 0.0
        return visualEffectView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(self.contentView)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.imageView)
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.visualEffectView)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    }

    override func updateViewConstraints()
    {
        super.updateViewConstraints()
        self.scrollView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor).active = true
        self.scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leadingAnchor).active = true
        self.scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.trailingAnchor).active = true
        self.scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.bottomAnchor).active = true

        self.imageView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: -navBarHeight).active = true
        self.imageView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.contentView.leadingAnchor).active = true
        self.imageView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.contentView.trailingAnchor).active = true
        // 150.0 or however tall you want your image
        self.imageView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(150.0 + navBarHeight).active = true

        self.visualEffectView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.imageView.centerXAnchor).active = true
        self.visualEffectView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.imageView.centerYAnchor).active = true
        self.visualEffectView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.imageView.widthAnchor).active = true
        self.visualEffectView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.imageView.heightAnchor).active = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        // Height just 1000 for example
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 1000.0)
        self.contentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.scrollView.contentSize.width, height: self.scrollView.contentSize.height)

    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        // Decrease size of denominator to make it blur faster
        self.visualEffectView.alpha = scrollView.contentOffset.y * 1.0 / (self.imageView.frame.height - (2.0 * navBarHeight))

        if scrollView.contentOffset.y > (self.imageView.frame.height - (2.0 * navBarHeight)) && self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundImageForBarMetrics(UIBarMetrics.Default) != nil
        {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
        }
        else if scrollView.contentOffset.y < (self.imageView.frame.height - (2.0 * navBarHeight)) && self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundImageForBarMetrics(UIBarMetrics.Default) == nil
        {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the effect logic is in `scrollViewDidScroll`. You start with the effect view over the image view but completely transparent as the y offset increases you increase the opacity and vice verse. Once you get to a point were only the height of the navigation bar is left for the  image switch to the `UINavigationBar`'s default background otherwise use `UIImage()` to make it transparent.

The result is:

[image]

[image]

Or a gif [here](http://bradgayman.com/screen.gif)

Obviously, Apple Music does other image manipulation to get soft vignettes, and you'll probably need to play around with the values to get it the way that you want it but this is should get you most of the way there.

Comment: hey man thanks a lot appreciate your effort . its woking pretty fine and great explanation though  , so far i learned that we have to add  blur to  imageView not NavigationBar and after a certain point of scrolling  we  have to make our transparent  NavigationBar  a default NavigationBar (please correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: You don't add the blur to the imageView per se. You are putting a `UIVisualEffectView`, which will blur all views below it. Since the image view is below it gets blurred. Adjusting the alpha of the `UIVisualEffectView` is what gives a blur in/out effect. You're correct about switching out the navigation bar. Looking at the Apple Music app, they also have a parallax effect for the image and they might only have the visual effect view on the bottom part of the image, possibly for performance reasons.